# Synchronized Statements in Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I'm reading the Thread Topic on [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and I'm trying to understand the Intrinsic Look.

I understand the different basic between **synchronized method**, **synchronized statement** and **synchronized static method** now.

In the synchronized statement section in that article, given a example and they said

> In this example, the addName method needs to synchronize changes to lastName and nameCount, but also needs to avoid synchronizing invocations of other objects' methods. (Invoking other objects' methods from synchronized code can create problems that are described in the section on Liveness.) Without synchronized statements, there would have to be a separate, unsynchronized method for the sole purpose of invoking nameList.add.

I really don't understand what they said. Please, explain it to me with a simple example.

Then, they said:

> Synchronized statements are also useful for improving concurrency with fine-grained synchronization. Suppose, for example, class MsLunch has two instance fields, c1 and c2, that are never used together. All updates of these fields must be synchronized, but there's no reason to prevent an update of c1 from being interleaved with an update of c2 — and doing so reduces concurrency by creating unnecessary blocking. Instead of using synchronized methods or otherwise using the lock associated with this, we create two objects solely to provide locks.

with example code

```java
public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            c1++;
        }
    }

    public void inc2() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            c2++;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I understand it? I think, it simply mention there are two object were created to manage the respective variable c1, c2, anything else?

**Update**

After reading all comments and the answers of @tgdavies and @michael, I'm extremely grateful for your support to help me to understand these concepts clearly.

For second quotes, I try to make a comparison to understand it.  `synchronized statement` actually is faster than `synchronized method`

1. MsLunch.java with synchronized statements

```java
public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            c1++;
        }
    }

    public void inc2() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            c2++;
        }
    }

    public long getC1() {
        return c1;
    }

    public long getC2() {
        return c2;
    }
}
```

2. MsLunch2.java with synchronized method

```java
public class MsLunch2 {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;

    public synchronized void inc1() {
        c1++;
    }

    public synchronized void inc2() {
        c2++;
    }

    public long getC1() {
        return c1;
    }

    public long getC2() {
        return c2;
    }
}
```

3. Test.java

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // synchronized statements
//        MsLunch ms = new MsLunch();
        // synchronized method
        MsLunch2 ms = new MsLunch2();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(start);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                ms.inc1();
            }
            System.out.println(ms.getC1());
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                ms.inc2();
            }
            System.out.println(ms.getC2());
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end);
        System.out.println("Time = " + (end - start)/1000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the section on Liveness (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/liveness.html)?

Comment: I don't read it yet. that quote contain two sentences, I'm quite confused with the first sentence

Comment: I've answered your first question now, but you should read that section to understand why we want to keep the scope of synchronised blocks small.

Comment: Tks, Be patient, I'm reading

Comment: ...imagine that `c1` and `c2` were public restrooms; if the methods were synchronized (i.e., there was *one* lock on `this`), it would mean that while restroom `c1` was occupied, nobody could use restroom `c2`. However, if they have separate locks, then both restrooms could be accessed concurrently. (Now imagine there were 10 restrooms, `c1` through `c10`, and how silly it'd be to have a single lock for all 10, when clearly the intent of the building architect was that all should be used concurrently.)

Comment: Important note: for these examples to be correct, the `getC1()` and `getC2()` method must use `synchronized` too and each getter must use the same object for synchronization as the method modifying the variable the getter reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code from your first question is:

```
public void addName(String name) {
    synchronized(this) {
        lastName = name;
        nameCount++;
    }
    nameList.add(name);
}
```

It's important that we don't call the `add` method of the `nameList` object while holding the lock on `this` because we don't know the behaviour of `add` -- maybe it takes a long time, for instance.

Without synchronised statements (i.e. if we only had synchronised methods), we would need to write:

```
public void addName(String name) {
    doSetLastName(name);
    nameList.add(name);
}

private synchronized doSetLastName(String name) {
        lastName = name;
        nameCount++;
}
```

Explanation of the phrase:

> avoid synchronizing invocations of other objects' methods

To 'avoid' doing something means not to do it, so we should "not synchronize invocations of other objects' methods"

An "invocation" is a call, so in the example above, we *invoke* the  `add` method on the `nameList` object.

Code in instance methods is run in the context of a particular object, that is, the object that `this` refers to, so "other objects' methods" are methods on objects which are not the `this` object. In the example above `add` is a method on the object `nameList`.

So we can rephrase it as "Don't call methods on other objects while holding locks" (unless of course you decide that you need to for thread safety.)

For your second question, imagine that `MsLunch` was implemented like this:

```
public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;

    public synchronized void inc1() {
            c1++;
    }

    public synchronized void inc2() {
            c2++;
    }
}
```

This is still perfectly thread safe, but because both synchronised sections lock in the `MsLunch` instance a thread calling `inc1` will be blocked by a thread calling `inc2`. That's unnecessary to preserve thread safety.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain this "but also needs to avoid synchronizing invocations of other objects' methods" on the my first quote for me to understand your answer easier?

Comment: What part of that phrase needs to be explained?

Comment: this whole group:  "avoid synchronizing invocations of other objects' methods"

Comment: wow, thanks for your amazing addition explanation. I might need a lot of time to understand your answer. So I will upvote as soon as possible.

Comment: What a horrible tutorial. Without providing additional context, most notably, whether `nameList` refers to a thread safe collection, developers **must not** move the invocation of the `add` method out of the `synchronized` block but keep it inside and ensure that every access to `nameList` is guarded too. A tutorial for beginners should focus on consistency instead of Liveness optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

> *"... I'm reading the Thread Topic on [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and I'm trying to understand the Intrinsic Look. ..."*

The concept of a *lock* is similar to the concept of a *[singleton class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)*.
It's, more or less, what the word *"intrinsic"* is describing—i.e., inherent, qualitative.

There is essentially a single instance, and only *1* thread can access it at a time.
When another thread encounters a *lock*, the *JVM* will delegate whether it must wait or continue—this is referred to as *"[blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing))"*, in *Java*.

> *"... I understand the different basic between **synchronized method**, **synchronized statement** and **synchronized static method** now. ..."*

They're very basic concepts.  You're simply *locking* a *class*, or *instance*, to prevent *concurrent* modification.
In other words, you can *"fine-tune"* the *lock*, in an effort to reduce *"blocking"*.

Despite this, though, the actual practice of *threading*, and *multi-threading*, can be quite complex.
I recommend reading *[Java Threads, 3rd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-threads-3rd/0596007825/)* by *O'Reilly Media*.

> *"... In the synchronized statement section in that article, given a example and they said ...
>
>
>
> ... I really don't understand what they said. Please, explain it to me with a simple example. ..."*

Essentially what they're saying is that it's good practice not to include *method invocations* inside of a *lock*.

> *"... Then, they said: ...
>
>
>
> ... How should I understand it? I think, it simply mention there are two object were created to manage the respective variable c1, c2, anything else? ..."*

Meaning, rather than *locking* a *MsLunch* instance, just *lock* an associated *Object*.

This is common practice throughout the *Java* framework.
Have a look at the *BufferedReader* class source-code, from the *[OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/)*.
*[GitHub – java/io/BufferedReader.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java)*

Comment: _"rather than locking a MsLunch instance, just lock an associated Object"_ —no, this isn't quite right. Using an "MsLunch instance" is also "an object" (specifically, `this`), and it doesn't matter if you use an "associated Object" or `this` —the point is, if you need and/or want to have _more than one_ lock, then you have to use a separate `Object` instance, because there's only *one* `this`. (I'm not sure if that clears anything up or not, but starting the answer w/ comparison to "Singleton"—a complicated/unrelated topic itself—isn't really going to help anyone understand concurrency.)

Comment: It is not in the least like the concept of a singleton, and ‘intrinsic’ does not mean ‘qualitative’. There can be many instances of locks. The JVM doesn’t have to ‘delegate whether it must wait or continue.’ Answer is largely nonsense.